# retrieving data avoiding google quotas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, quota

I need to poll 60 tables and get information from a couple of cells in each spreadsheet. I created a google app script that does just that. At first I wanted to write all of the cells (about 300) into another google spreadsheet using the same script, however, the quota only allows 50 writing entries per day. Is there a way to get all the stored data? Maybe download it as a CSV? Or else? Or is there a way to write all of the cells into a spreadsheet in one go, avoiding the "50 entries" limit?

Thank you!

ADD-on
(I KNOW the code is very busy and not very algorithm efficient - I was trying to get the hang of it. To see how it all works.)

```
function findFolder() {
  var row = 3;

  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var folderIter = dApp.getFoldersByName ("П.,6");
  var folder = folderIter.next();  
  var filesIter = folder.getFiles();


  while (filesIter.hasNext()) { 

  var file = filesIter.next();
  var fileID = file.getId();
  var fileName = file.getName();

  Logger.log("file:" + file);

  values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get (fileID,'Журнал!F2:P5');     

  var valuesReadable = [];
  //0:title, 1:group, 2:teacher, 3:place, 4:room, 5:timetable

  valuesReadable [0] = values.values [0][1];
  valuesReadable [1] = values.values [1][1];
  valuesReadable [2] = values.values [2][1];
  valuesReadable [3] = values.values [0][9];
  valuesReadable [4] = values.values [0][10];
  valuesReadable [5] = values.values [1][9];



  Logger.log (valuesReadable [0]);
  Logger.log (valuesReadable [1]);
  Logger.log (valuesReadable [2]);
  Logger.log (valuesReadable [3]);
  Logger.log (valuesReadable [4]);
  Logger.log (valuesReadable [5]);

  var titles = [];

  titles [0] = "название группы";
  titles [1] = "курс";
  titles [2] = "ФИО"
  titles [3] = "дом, каб"
  titles [4] = 'кабинет';
  titles [5] = "день, время"

  var checkResult = [];
  //0:title, 1:group, 2:teacher, 3:place, 4:room, 5:timetable

  checkResult [0] = "Курс 01";
  checkResult [1] = "1";
  checkResult [2] = "ФИО"
  checkResult [3] = "дом, каб"
  checkResult [4] = '';
  checkResult [5] = "день, время"


  var sheet1CheckResult = [];


  var a = 0;
  while (a < 6) {
     if (valuesReadable [a] == checkResult [a]) 

     {
       Logger.log ("поле: " + titles [a] + " не заполнено");
       sheet1CheckResult [a] = "не заполнено";
     }

    else {
      Logger.log ("поле: " + titles [a] + " заполнено");
      sheet1CheckResult [a] = "заполнено";
    }

  a++;
  }


  var data = [[fileName]]; 
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = data;
  var cell = 'A' + row;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'someReference',cell,{
       valueInputOption: 'RAW'});


  var data =  [[sheet1CheckResult[0]]]; 
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  Logger.log ("data: " + data);
  valueRange.values = data;
  Logger.log ("valueRange: " + valueRange.values);
  var cell = 'D' + row;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'someReference',cell,{
       valueInputOption: 'RAW'});


  var data = [[sheet1CheckResult[1]]]; 
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = data;
  var cell = 'E' + row;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'someReference',cell,{
       valueInputOption: 'RAW'});


  var data = [[sheet1CheckResult[2]]]; 
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = data;
  var cell = 'F' + row;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'someReference',cell,{
       valueInputOption: 'RAW'});


  var data = [[sheet1CheckResult[3]]]; 
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = data;
  var cell = 'G' + row;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'someReference',cell,{
       valueInputOption: 'RAW'});


  var data = [[sheet1CheckResult[4]]]; 
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = data;
  var cell = 'H' + row;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'someReference',cell,{
       valueInputOption: 'RAW'});

  var data = [[sheet1CheckResult[5]]]; 
  var valueRange = Sheets.newValueRange();
  valueRange.values = data;
  var cell = 'I' + row;
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, 'someReference',cell,{
       valueInputOption: 'RAW'});

  row ++;  
  }
}
```

Comment: You can store all of the data in one array and write the array all at once with one `setValues()` which is a method of the Range Class. I doubt that quota of 50 writings per day.  I know I've done way more than that in one day.  Something seem fishy. Perhaps you can share the text of the actual error message or a reference to that information.

Comment: This is what I get. "API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.update failed with error: Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit 'Write requests per user per 100 seconds' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:495790693024'. (line 114, file "Code")"

Comment: I uploaded the code above

Comment: As you are using Apps Script, try using [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) instead of the Sheets API.

Comment: I am not sure if this counts as an answer. However, if someone faces the same problem. I implemented both ideas in the same code (storing info in an array first, using sheetApp) and it worked. I made a script that went through 200 spreadsheets and made a summary table with 900 entries. It worked.